# Calculate Euclidean distance matrix using a big.matrix object

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, sparse-matrix, r-bigmemory

I have an object of class `big.matrix` in `R` with dimension `778844 x 2`. The values are all integers (kilometres). My objective is to calculate the Euclidean distance matrix using the `big.matrix` and have as a result an object of class `big.matrix`. I would like to know if there is an optimal way of doing that.

The reason for my choice of using the class `big.matrix` is memory limitation. I could transform my `big.matrix` to an object of class `matrix` and calculate the Euclidean distance matrix using `dist()`. However, `dist()` would return an object of size that would not be allocated in the memory.

**Edit**

The following answer was given by John W. Emerson, author and maintainer of the `bigmemory` package:

> You could use big algebra I expect, but this would also be a very nice use case for Rcpp via sourceCpp(), and very short and easy.  But in short, we don't even attempt to provide high-level features (other than the basics which we implemented as proof-of-concept).  No single algorithm could cover all use cases once you start talking out-of-memory big.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way using `RcppArmadillo`.  Much of this is very similar to the [RcppGallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpparmadillo/).  This will return a `big.matrix` with the associated pairwise (by row) euclidean distances.  I like to wrap my `big.matrix` functions in a wrapper function to create a cleaner syntax (i.e. avoid the `@address` and other initializations.

Note - as we are using bigmemory (and therefore concerned with RAM usage) I have this example returned the N-1 x N-1 matrix of only lower triangular elements.  You could modify this but this is what I threw together.

euc_dist.cpp

```
// To enable the functionality provided by Armadillo's various macros,
// simply include them before you include the RcppArmadillo headers.
#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, BH, bigmemory)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// The following header file provides the definitions for the BigMatrix
// object
#include <bigmemory/BigMatrix.h>

// C++11 plugin
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

template <typename T>
void BigArmaEuclidean(const Mat<T>& inBigMat, Mat<T> outBigMat) {

  int W = inBigMat.n_rows;

  for(int i = 0; i < W - 1; i++){
      for(int j=i+1; j < W; j++){
          outBigMat(j-1,i) = sqrt(sum(pow((inBigMat.row(i) - inBigMat.row(j)),2)));
      }
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void BigArmaEuc(SEXP pInBigMat, SEXP pOutBigMat) {
  // First we tell Rcpp that the object we've been given is an external
  // pointer.
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pInBigMat);
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpOutMat(pOutBigMat);


  int type = xpMat->matrix_type();
  switch(type) {
      case 1:
        BigArmaEuclidean(
            arma::Mat<char>((char *)xpMat->matrix(), xpMat->nrow(), xpMat->ncol(), false),
            arma::Mat<char>((char *)xpOutMat->matrix(), xpOutMat->nrow(), xpOutMat->ncol(), false)
        );
        return;

      case 2:
        BigArmaEuclidean(
          arma::Mat<short>((short *)xpMat->matrix(), xpMat->nrow(), xpMat->ncol(), false),
          arma::Mat<short>((short *)xpOutMat->matrix(), xpOutMat->nrow(), xpOutMat->ncol(), false)
        );
        return;

      case 4:
        BigArmaEuclidean(
          arma::Mat<int>((int *)xpMat->matrix(), xpMat->nrow(), xpMat->ncol(), false),
          arma::Mat<int>((int *)xpOutMat->matrix(), xpOutMat->nrow(), xpOutMat->ncol(), false)
        );
        return;

      case 8:
        BigArmaEuclidean(
          arma::Mat<double>((double *)xpMat->matrix(), xpMat->nrow(), xpMat->ncol(), false),
          arma::Mat<double>((double *)xpOutMat->matrix(), xpOutMat->nrow(), xpOutMat->ncol(), false)
        );
        return;

      default:
        // We should never get here, but it resolves compiler warnings.
        throw Rcpp::exception("Undefined type for provided big.matrix");
  }

}
```

My little wrapper

```
bigMatrixEuc <- function(bigMat){
    zeros <- big.matrix(nrow = nrow(bigMat)-1,
                        ncol = nrow(bigMat)-1,
                        init = 0,
                        type = typeof(bigMat))
    BigArmaEuc(bigMat@address, zeros@address)
    return(zeros)
}
```

The test

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("euc_dist.cpp")

library(bigmemory)

set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4)
bm <- as.big.matrix(mat)

# Call new euclidean function
bm_out <- bigMatrixEuc(bm)[]

# pull out the matrix elements for out purposes
distMat <- as.matrix(dist(mat))
distMat[upper.tri(distMat, diag=TRUE)] <- 0
distMat <- distMat[2:4, 1:3]

# check if identical 
all.equal(bm_out, distMat, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I ran the above, and got `bm_out` as a `matrix`. Reading the wrapper, I had thought that `bm_out` should have been a `big.matrix`. Was I wrong and this example indeed should yield a `matrix`? Any way to have `bm_out` directly as `big.matrix` (rather than `matrix` which I pass to `as.big.matrix`)

Comment: @Ricky just remove the brackets then '[]' as they are only used to confirm the output is the same as from 'dist'.