# Most efficient way to calculate euclidean distances in a large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, geospatial, distance, r-sf

I would like to find what is the most **memory and time** efficient way to calculate euclidean distances on a large matrix. I've ran this small benchmark below comparing a few packages I know: `parallelDist`, `geodist`, `fields` and `stats`. I've also considered this [customized function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958646/calculate-euclidean-distance-matrix-using-a-big-matrix-object)  that combines `Rcpp`and `bigmemory`. Here are the results I've found (reprex below), but I'd like to know whether there are other efficient pacakges / solutions to do this task:

### Results

```
benchmrk
#>   package   time        alloc
#>1: parDist  0.298 5.369186e-04
#>2:  fields  1.079 9.486198e-03
#>3:    rcpp 54.422 2.161113e+00
#>4:   stats  0.770 5.788603e+01
#>5: geodist  2.513 1.157635e+02

# plot
ggplot(benchmrk, aes(x=alloc , y=time, color= package, label=package)) +
  geom_label(alpha=.5) +
  coord_trans(x="log10", y="log10") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

### Reprex

```
library(parallelDist)
library(geodist)
library(fields)
library(stats)
library(bigmemory)
library(Rcpp)

library(lineprof)
library(geobr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)


# data input
df <- geobr::read_weighting_area()
gc(reset = T)

# convert projection to UTM
df <- st_transform(df, crs = 3857)

# get spatial coordinates
coords <- suppressWarnings(st_coordinates( st_centroid(df) ))

# prepare customized rcpp function
sourceCpp("euc_dist.cpp")

bigMatrixEuc <- function(bigMat){
  zeros <- big.matrix(nrow = nrow(bigMat)-1,
                      ncol = nrow(bigMat)-1,
                      init = 0,
                      type = typeof(bigMat))
  BigArmaEuc(bigMat@address, zeros@address)
  return(zeros)
}




### Start tests
perf_fields  <- lineprof(dist_fields <- fields::rdist(coords) )
perf_geodist <- lineprof(dist_geodist <- geodist::geodist(coords, measure = "cheap") )
perf_stats   <- lineprof(dist_stats <- stats::dist(coords) )
perf_parDist <- lineprof(dist_parDist <- parallelDist::parDist(coords, method = "euclidean") )
perf_rcpp <- lineprof(dist_rcpp <- bigMatrixEuc( as.big.matrix(coords) ) )

perf_fields$package  <- 'fields'
perf_geodist$package <- 'geodist'
perf_stats$package   <- 'stats'
perf_parDist$package <- 'parDist'
perf_rcpp$package <- 'rcpp'


# gather results
benchmrk <- rbind(perf_fields, perf_geodist, perf_stats , perf_parDist, perf_rcpp)
benchmrk <- setDT(benchmrk)[, .(time  =sum(time), alloc = sum(alloc)), by=package][order(alloc)]
benchmrk
```

Comment: Hi! I don't know the answer to your question but I just want to note that, AFAIK, `geodist::geodist()` does make sense only when the input data is specified using lon-lat coordinates (and not UTM).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @agila.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I try to propose an answer 'theoretically'.

I think a combination of the `rccp` approach ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958646/calculate-euclidean-distance-matrix-using-a-big-matrix-object)) and the `parDist` ([here](https://github.com/alexeckert/parallelDist/blob/master/src/parallelDist.cpp)) might allow for working on very large data sets while keeping execution times at an acceptable level?

Unfortunately, I did not work with `rccp`, `RcppParallel` nor `RcppArmadillo`yet. But it seems the parDist and the rccp-big.matrix approach build upon the same 'infrastructure'.

Maybe some more experienced users will take up the challenge.